# Can I connect two external monitors on one USB-C port

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, thinkpad, xrandr, usb-c

I have a [Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 7](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-type-20a7-20a8) with Ubuntu 18.04. This devise has one HDMI port and two USB-C port. I want to connect two external monitors on one USB-C port.

When I ran `xrandr`, I get the following:

```
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   ...
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Then I got one of these [USB-C adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q9JXWTP) with 2-HDMI ports, connected it to the laptop using the USB-C port and connected the two external monitors on the HDMI output of the hub.

The problem is that the two monitors show exactly the same thing, and when I go the Display setting, I only see one monitor. It seems that the two HDMI ports on the hub, are detected as one device.

This same thing happens when I use the other USB-C port. So my question is that if there is a way to have two external monitors using this hub or similar hubs from one USB-C port.

Comment: it's like you said, it's a hub (a hub is just something that would duplicate a signal from one source and copy it at all his destination); you re looking on something like a switch, but i don't know if it exist for HDMI (I think it would be really ugly)

Comment: Thanks, so a hub with 2 HDMI ports can just do mirroring? I though it can actually handle two monitors independently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Link's fine print says only Windows supports the [Multi-Stream Transport](https://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/sln295251/how-to-configure-u2415-monitor-daisy-chaining-on-intel-hd-graphics?lang=en) (MST) required to daisy chain two monitors. As such I suspect that is why monitors are mirrored.

Check with vendor perhaps there is a work around or it's not too late to return it and get your eighty bucks back.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. So Ubuntu does not support MST? Or is it hub specific?

Comment: I would shop around for a different hub that supports two with extended desktop. Off the top of my head I can't recommend one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a dock may (repeat, may) solve your problem: Lenovo advertises multiple docks, but [this one](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd029981) explicitly says it supports two external monitors. I would confirm that with Lenovo Support before buying, though.

Comment: Thanks. So is USB-C limited to only driving one monitor at a time?

Comment: Depends on the PC that's running it. I see nothing wrong with checking with Lenovo Support to see if there's another way. https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-7th-gen-type-20r1-20r2/contactus